# Trouble displaying a specific number in a loop without scientific notation in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Ok, so I'm writing a program, of which the overall purpose is not necessarily important, but there is a point in the program where I'm trying to print out a table that displays n, n!, and x^n (where n and x are both user inputs).

The code I have thus far is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float x, xn, factorial = 1;
    float n = 1;

    cout << "Enter an angle in radians: ";
    cin >> x;
    while (n <= 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter the number of terms to be included into the Taylor series expansion: ";
        cin >> n;
        if (n < 1)
        {
            cout << "Error! Try again\n";
        }
    }

    cout << "n\tn!\tx^n\t\n";
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout << i;
        factorial *= i;
        cout << "\t" << factorial;
        xn = pow(x, i);
        cout << "\t" << setprecision(i) << xn;
        cout << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, the problem I'm having is that it begins to display my x^n in scientific notation after it goes past 5 decimal places. I do not want it to do this. I tried using setprecision(i) as you might have noticed, but that doesn't do the job. It's confusing me because a.) I'm not sure I know the code I need to use to get it to stop displaying in scientific notation and b.) I don't want the other outputs for n and n! to be affected by the manipulation I'm going to have to use on the output of x^n, which is tricky for me because they're all calculated and outputted in the same loop. I'm at a loss here, any help is much appreciated! I'd post an image of the program output for you all, but it seems I need more reputation to do that.

Also, on a side note, if you have any advice on a better way to format my table, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you print `xn`, you can switch the stream to use fixed notation, and after it, switch back to default float:

```
cout << "\t" << setprecision(i) << std::fixed << xn << std::defaultfloat;
```

References: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed

Comment: This does the trick! Thanks a bunch. I also have a bit of a question - I tried almost this exact same code before coming here, but i had the std::fixed precede the setprecision(i) (where the opposite is the case in your code) - and it did not work. Do you know why that is? I feel like maybe I'm not fully understanding how the two statements work in tandem.

Comment: No reason for that. You can see here ([coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bf869a1868c2d56)) that it is working even with positions swapped